# If statement based on a counter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to know how can I use `IF` statement (in maybe a for or while loop) to change the value of the cell based on a condition of a counter.

```
=IF(Counter=1,M2,IF(Counter=2,M3,IF(Counter=3,M4,....
```

if my counter = #, the cell value is replaced by a value of M(#+1) as shown in the example above.

the counter is from 1 to 999.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDIRECT`

`=INDIRECT("M"&Counter+1)`

notes: `OFFSET` or `INDEX` work too

Comment: I'd recommend index if possible - the other two are volatile.